# dump directory data to a file for new/modified comparison later on a linux server

Tags: linux, backup

Is it possible to take some kind of "dump" of a directory on a Linux (Ubuntu) server that I can later use to compare against for new/modified files?

The idea being something like this:

1. Dump directory data (like file hashes)
2. 24 hours later I take another dump and compare against #1 to find new or modified files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dump hashes first time into new file hashes-before

```
md5sum my_dir/* > hashes-before
```

dump hashes second time into new file hashes-after

```
md5sum my_dir/* > hashes-after
```

compare both files

```
diff hashes-before hashes-after
```